# MYSQL Duplicate Column name error (SELECT FROM (TABLE), (SELECT * FROM JOIN TABLE))

Tags: mysql

I am trying to develop social App, and filter other users that match the condition that current user are looking for in MYSQL. However, I got stuck while I was writing the query. Can anyone help me?

My SQL query look likes:

```
SELECT base.id FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE username='username') matchCondition,
(SELECT * FROM (((Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.username = Table3.username) INNER JOIN
Table4 ON Table3.username = Table4.username) INNER JOIN
Table5 ON Table4.username = Table5.username)
WHERE ad.username != 'username' AND role='user') base WHERE(...)
```

And I get error of "Duplicate column name 'username'"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply changing the column name of "username" to another name on different table. eg. t1_username, t2_username etc.